# Map array inside an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've the following complex JSON object that has got array and array inside an array. How can parse those arrays and create an object array for each element in the array. I'm using lodash library in my project, just in case if there are any functions available.

```
   {
  studentId: 123
  name: XYZ
  phone: 34234234
  gender: M
  subjects: [{
     studentId: 123
     subjectName: Math
     scores:50
    assignments:[
     {
        type: Internal,
        submitted: yes,
        status: failed 
     },
     {
        type: External,
        submitted: yes,
        status: passed 
     }] 
},
{
     studentId: 123
     subjectName: Science
     score: 20
     assignments:[
     {
        type: Internal,
        submitted: yes,
        status: passed 
     },
     {
        type: External,
        submitted: yes,
        status: failed 
     }]
}] 

}
```

Expecting:

```
[{
  studentId:123,
  name: XYZ
  phone: 34234234
  gender: M,  
  subjectName: Math
  scores:50
  assignments:[
     {
        type: Internal,
        submitted: yes,
        status: failed 
     },
     {
        type: External,
        submitted: yes,
        status: passed 
     }]
},
{
 studentId:123,
  name: XYZ
  phone: 34234234
  gender: M,  
  subjectName: science
  scores:20
  assignments:[
     {
        type: Internal,
        submitted: yes,
        status: failed 
     },
     {
        type: External,
        submitted: yes,
        status: passed 
     }]
}
]
```

Comment: That's invalid JSON. You're missing quotes around the keys and string values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) to get the `details` of the student without the `subjects` array, use these `details` to transform each item in the subjects array using [defaults](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#defaults) through [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map).

```
var details = _.omit(data, 'subjects');
var result = _.map(data.subjects, function(subject) {
  return _.defaults({}, details, subject);
});
```

```js
var data = {
    studentId: '123',
    name: 'XYZ',
    phone: '34234234',
    gender: 'M',
    subjects: [{
        studentId: '123',
        subjectName: 'Math',
        scores: 50,
        assignments: [{
            type: 'Internal',
            submitted: 'yes',
            status: 'failed'
          },
          {
            type: 'External',
            submitted: 'yes',
            status: 'passed'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        studentId: '123',
        subjectName: 'Science',
        score: 20,
        assignments: [{
            type: 'Internal',
            submitted: 'yes',
            status: 'passed'
          },
          {
            type: 'External',
            submitted: 'yes',
            status: 'failed'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
};

var details = _.omit(data, 'subjects');
var result = _.map(data.subjects, function(subject) {
  return _.defaults({}, details, subject);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ryeballar. This is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use [Normalizr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr) package. It's very useful and takes all care about your collections even if they're nested.